# How Can I Create A Specific Arc On Face?

Tags: modeling

Is there anyway that can I make a specific arc (and specific radius that I can't do with bevel) between two vertices in face?

Like in the in image;
[image]

Comment: you can select the top left vertex and bevel it (ctrl B then in the Operator box on the bottom left of your 3D view, click on Vertex and play with the parameters)

Comment: Do you know a 3rd point on the arc?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
select the point

[image]

If you want accurate:

[image]

scale it to square first

[image]

width = 0.5　this is a 1/4 circle with 0.5 radius

[image]

scale back to previous rato

[image]

If you want special mathematical curve, you can add a Curve obj and convert to mesh to do the Boolean or find some addon.